# Tkinter menu spontaneously adding extra item

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm writing a Tkinter program that so far creates a window with a menu bar, a File menu, and a single item. The menu is successfully created, but with two items, the first being one that I did not specify, whose name is "-----".

If I don't add an item, the spontaneous one is still added. This still happens if I specify tearoff=0.

Any idea why this is happening?

Windows 11, Python 3.12.2, Tkinter and Tcl 8.6.

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("800x600")

menubar = tk.Menu(window)
window.config(menu=menubar)

fileMenu = tk.Menu(menubar)
fileMenu.add_command(
    label="Exit",
    command=window.destroy,
)
menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=fileMenu, underline=0)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: I have wrote and tested the basic Tkinter app for that however in both cases it worked well. Can u provide your code part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that way it works. I think u put `tearoff=0`   in `menubar` instead of `fileMenu`. If you put your `tearoff=0` in `menubar` it won't affect `fileMenu`. So, u need to specifically put `tearoff=0` in specific `tk.Menu()`

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("800x600")

menubar = tk.Menu(window)
window.config(menu=menubar)

fileMenu = tk.Menu(menubar,tearoff=0)
fileMenu.add_command(
    label="Exit",
    command=window.destroy,
)
menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=fileMenu, underline=0)

window.mainloop()
```